# UnboundLocalError with my program

Tags: django

I had to create a new bookmark application but where is my problem I cannot find please help me....

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post your actual code, not an image of your code.

Comment: thanks for your concern friend oli charlesworth.. i will keep that in mind from next time... !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please post your actual codes.**

About your question, you must put the else statement after the request POST statement not in the form.is_valid(). Because if you put your else statement after form.is_valid statement, the render will not find the variable

```
def register_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ...........
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        variable = RequestContext(request, {'form':form})

    return ......
```

Comment: problem solved, tanks Catherine... You are really helpful :) few days earlier you solved my problem really thank you... !! can i have your email id please ??